# Search a record in database using C#

Tags: c#, dataset

First at all, I am a beginner in C#, so sorry if this problem is easy (or not) but I'm blocked.

I'm trying to find a Record in my Database using that code :

```
 public int chercherDansDataSet(string search)
    {
        DataRow[] foundRows;
        String idSearch;
        int result = 0;
        int idKey = 0 ;
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        string research = "last_name = '"+search+"'";


        foundRows = dt.Select(research);

        result = foundRows.Length;


        if(result == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Aucun résultat");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            DataRow rowBack;
            rowBack = foundRows[0];
            idSearch = rowBack[0].ToString();
            idKey = Int32.Parse(idSearch);
            return idKey; 
        }
    }
```

But every time I'm trying it, I get:

> No records found

("Aucun Résultat" in french in my code, the result when my `if` get `result == 0`)

When I debug, my datatable isn't empty so I think it is not the problem :

[image: Here is the Datatable returned by dt]

My goal is to return the ID of the searched line....

Here is my config for my Dataset, but I don't think the problem comes from here:

```
 private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();
        da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
        System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
        con.Close();

        return dat_set;
    }
```

And there is the Form1Load, where my ds is set :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
            conString = Properties.Settings.Default.EmployeeConnectionString;

            objConnect.connection_string = conString;
            objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

            ds = objConnect.GetConnection;
            MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            NavigateRecords();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);

        }

    }
```

And my class "DatabaseConnection" :

```
class DatabaseConnection
{
    private string sql_string;
    private string strCon;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1;


    public string Sql
    {

        set
        {
            sql_string = value;

        }
    }

    public string connection_string
    {

        set { strCon = value; }

    }

    public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection
    {

        get { return MyDataSet(); }

    }

    public DataSet dat_set { get; private set; }

    private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();
        da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
        System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
        con.Close();

        return dat_set;
    }

    public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);

        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: From the picture is not clear. It is "last name" or "last_name"? And what is the value of the variable _search_?

Comment: keep in mind, all user input should be parameterised to prevent SQL injection

Comment: also, why not just retrieve the record you want from  the database, instead of a datatable of all values and searching through them? You are doing 2 searches instead of a single one

Comment: @Takarii This isn't SQL searching, they are searching a DataTable located in memory. SQL injection can't occur here

Comment: @draken the dataset is retrieved from a database.

Comment: @Takarii They are filling the DataTable with all their data, check the last code section

Comment: @Takarii But there is no search query done on the database, that is done afterwards once the data has been retrieved into the `DataTable`. The search is done on the `DataTable` after it has been populated by a non SQL injectable query

Comment: @Vianney You may need to double check the names of your columns in your `DataTable`, have a check by putting a breakpoint before you search and manually checking, or adding a function to print the column names (Not titles) to the console

Comment: Still seems like an extra step. Why not query the database directly instead of pulling all records then sifting through them?

Comment: @Takarii Many reasons, at this moment it appears the OP is attempting to show the data to a user, then after the data is already populated, allow the user to do a search. You would rather the OP query the DB, then query the DB again when they want to do a search? Unless the data could be changing, seems overkill

Comment: @Draken id rather the OP query the DB for the exact data that is needed with a single query, not multiple.

Comment: @Takarii I didn't know i could do a search directly in the Database : i follow this tutorial http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html to learn C# and the moment about the Database was confusing for me.

Comment: what is the value of "sql_string" is it "select * from YourTable"

Comment: One observation.  There is an ellipsis after the values for a lot of the values in that table.  Could this (presumably trailing spaces) be messing up the query?

Comment: Sql_string = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employees"

Comment: @Steve it's "last_name", i already tried without the "_" but it's just a view bug ^^

Comment: @OldBoyCoder you have a point here. Probably the fields are filled with spaces causing the search to fail.

Comment: Try string research = "last_name LIKE '"+search+"%'";

Comment: @Vianneyyour you already have the majority of the code needed to specifically query the database. your `sql_string` variable can be used to perform the exact query you need. However, as i prevously mentioned, you need to make sure you parameterise it if you are passing a user value to the query to protect against sql injection

Comment: @OldBoyCoder Argh, i was afraid about this solution because i thought this is the problem too but i have no idea how to ignore the blank in the Database

Comment: @Vianneyyour as I comment above try string research = "last_name LIKE '"+search+"%'".  Ideally you should get rid of those trailing spaces but that is a different question (which we can solve).

Comment: @OldBoyCoder, i got an Syntax Error with this query

Comment: @Vianneyyour can you paste your line of code back as a comment so I can check it.  Was the syntax error at compile time or run time?  I forgot to add the semi-colon at the end of line, I'm assuming that you put that it in?

Comment: @OldBoyCoder, at run time, I get : System.Data.SyntaxErrorException
It was just an Exception, not an error but the program crash ^^

Comment: @Vianneyyour Thanks, can you post the full detailed message from the exception?

Comment: It's too long to post here

Comment: Post as much as you can.  I'm interested in the 'Message' part of the exception

Comment: I found how to get out the trailling space, but it still not working :/

Answer (score 0):

First you must move the declaration of your Dataset to the top of your form as global like :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      System.Data.DataSet ds= new System.Data.DataSet();
      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
```

And remove the declaration from your procedure `MyDataSet`
Then in your `chercherDansDataSet` function you mast use the variable `dat_set` instead of  `ds`:

```
  DataTable dt = dat_set.Tables[0];
```

instead of

```
 DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

Try to add "[]" to you variable and a spaces like :

```
string research = "[last_name] = '" + search + "'";
foundRows = dt.Select(research);
result = foundRows.Length;
```

If you don't have "_" in your datatable try with :

```
string research = "[last name] = '" + search + "'";
```

Comment: Remove the declaration from your procedure MyDataSet Then in your chercherDansDataSet

Comment: This variable is used in different form into my solution, if I move the declaration, other method does'nt work properly

Comment: can you show the declaration of "ds" and affectation ,beacuse in you code the DS is empty ?

Comment: i edited my answer ,you can add a declaration of DS above your form load

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you can do it using a dataset, here is sample code:

```
ds = getUserName();  //search using parameterized query and return record found as ds

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)  //if record found more than 1 row, mean doesnt empty
{
    return ds;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Aucun résultat");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Ahah thanks but the problem is not that my Datatable are empty or not, is that the method "Select" never find a correlate row :/

Comment: I just suggested another approach for him, why simply vote down me, if like this who still will sharing here?

Comment: downvote is likely because the answer doesn't answer the question.